# Android: Push Notification on Rooted Devices

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, rooted-device

I am working on *Push Notification* in which I have to show notifications on a rooted phone. I have done *Push Notification* on non-rooted phones and is working fine.

Is there any way to apply *Push Notification* on rooted phone, I googled so many examples but all are showing simple *Push Notification* that I have implemented.

I am still confused about if there's anyway or is it possible to apply *Push Notification* on rooted devices.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you don't need anything special.The same code will work on rooted devices

Comment: @AnirudhSharma actully the phone which i rooted was damaged so i am unable to test that...:(

Comment: well yes it works on rooted devices as well.